# Weird figure randomly began showing up and won't go away

Tags: compiling, smartdiagram

This weird figure (image below) randomly showed up at the beginning of my document (occupying a after I added the smartdiagram package to make a chart. I've a bunch of different things and this diagram won't go away. What do you think is the likely cause and how can I fix it?

[image]

Edit: I should mention that I removed the **entire** text (all of the sections) and it still is there. Here is the preamble:

```
    %% Documentclass:
    \documentclass[manuscript]{stjour}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{caption}
    %\usepackage{neuralnetwork}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    %\tikzset{
    %  level/.style   = { ultra thick, blue },
    %  connect/.style = { dashed, red },
    %  notice/.style  = { draw, rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={#1} },
    %  label/.style   = { text width=2cm }
    %}

    %% Manuscript, for double spaced, larger fonts
    % \documentclass[manuscript]{stjour}
    %% Only needed if you use `manuscript' option
    %\journalname{Open Mind}
    \journalname{Computational Psychiatry}
    \def\layersep{2.5cm}

    %%%%%%%%%%% Please supply information %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %% For Open Mind:
    %% Supplementary Materials:
    \supplementslinks{dx.doi.org/X}

    %% For Computational Psychiatry
    \supportinginfo{dx.doi.org/X}
    %% If no conflicts, this command doesn't need to be used
    %% \conflictsofinterest{}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% author definitions should be placed here:

    %% example definition
    %\def\taupav{\tau_{\mathrm{Pav}}}
    \begin{document}

    \bibliography{b}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet -- as usual here -- **compilable** and resulting in your issue, **then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...**

Comment: Thanks! And this code snippet was copied from my document (and compiles in it).

Comment: Where can we find `stjour.cls`? Do you get the thing also with `lorem ipsum` instead of `\bibliography{b}`? (We don't have `b.bib`, and if the problem can be reproduced without the bibliography, that makes for a better example.)